# Optimizing For Loop for Large Amount of Data

Tags: vb.net, optimization, loops

```
For indY as Integer = 1 To xLsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
If aRndLAcctNo.Contains(xLsheet.Cells(indy + 1, 2).Value.ToString()) Then
aRndLTotProd.Add(Indy)
End If
Next
```

When I set it too 'To 1000' it works well. But when I use 'To  xLsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count' it throws an error. My excel file contains 16000 rows. Please help how to optimize For Loop. Or if you may suggest another way where I can get the Row of the excel file which contains an Item that is already in the arndLacctNo List of string..

Comment: What kind of error is being thrown?

Comment: Just a guess. Maybe the integer datatype is too small? Try writng:
For indY as Long = 1

Comment: Isn't it `For indY as Integer = 1 To xLsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` instead of `For indY as Integer = 1 To xLsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem that you had here was your not studying the text of the error message, and secondarily also not including the error message in your question here.

Supposing you received something like this:

```
prog.vb (5,63) : Error VBNC30205: Expected end of statement.
```

This was telling you, "in file `prog.vb`, on line 5, in column 63, you have a typo; instead of the end of statement you have something else".

In my case, line 5, column 63 is where a `Then` without a corresponding `If` lurks.  Look at your own error message, find your own code location, and remove the offending keyword there.  It is a simple syntax error that has nothing to do with the number of rows.